# Dates in Excel - sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

Is it possible to sort a list of dates by week?  For example, if I have a list of specific dates and I want to group them into week 1, week 2, week 50 of the year, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the date already, then you can use the `WEEKNUM` formula to show which week of the year that date falls into.

```
=WEEKNUM(B1,1)
```

B1 denotes a date, for example if B1 contained `5/14/2014`, then `WEEKNUM` would return `20`. Obviously you will need to substitute B1 for the cell reference your data is in.

You can then use the sort function to sort by weeks ascending or descending.

**NOTE**: This method will not work if your data is split across two years.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/weeknum-function-HP010343016.aspx

```
=WEEKNUM (serial_num, [return_type])
```